# ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: -11) local_rank: 0 of binary: ..../python

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, distributed-computing

```html
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: -11) local_rank: 0 (pid: 3680358) of binary: /home/lifesci/ekeys/anaconda3/envs/minigpt4-4/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lifesci/ekeys/anaconda3/envs/minigpt4-4/bin/torchrun", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('torch==2.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'torchrun')())
  File "/home/lifesci/ekeys/anaconda3/envs/minigpt4-4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/errors/__init__.py", line 346, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lifesci/ekeys/anaconda3/envs/minigpt4-4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 794, in main
    run(args)
  File "/home/lifesci/ekeys/anaconda3/envs/minigpt4-4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 785, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/home/lifesci/ekeys/anaconda3/envs/minigpt4-4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 134, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/home/lifesci/ekeys/anaconda3/envs/minigpt4-4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 250, in launch_agent
    raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError: 
=========================================================
train.py FAILED
---------------------------------------------------------
Failures:
[1]:
  time      : 2023-10-21_17:36:57
  host      : gnode10.hanhai22.scc.ustc.edu.cn
  rank      : 1 (local_rank: 1)
  exitcode  : -11 (pid: 3680359)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) received by PID 3680359
[2]:
  time      : 2023-10-21_17:36:57
  host      : gnode10.hanhai22.scc.ustc.edu.cn
  rank      : 2 (local_rank: 2)
  exitcode  : -11 (pid: 3680360)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) received by PID 3680360
[3]:
  time      : 2023-10-21_17:36:57
  host      : gnode10.hanhai22.scc.ustc.edu.cn
  rank      : 3 (local_rank: 3)
  exitcode  : -11 (pid: 3680361)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) received by PID 3680361
---------------------------------------------------------
Root Cause (first observed failure):
[0]:
  time      : 2023-10-21_17:36:57
  host      : gnode10.hanhai22.scc.ustc.edu.cn
  rank      : 0 (local_rank: 0)
  exitcode  : -11 (pid: 3680358)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) received by PID 3680358
=========================================================
```

When I do distributed training with pytorch, during the initialization phase, I get this error .what is the reason?

I tried to switch to different versions of pytorch and cuda, but it still reported errors.

Comment: Please post the error as text not the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have revised it.

Comment: @ekesys were you able to solve this...I am also facing the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77382185/yolov7-multi-gpu-constantly-gives-runtime-error